# how to display value of the checked checkboxes?

Tags: php, checkbox

```
$section = mysql_query("SELECT services.services, services.price FROM services WHERE pet_breed = 'Dog'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($section))
   {

    echo "<br><input type='checkbox' id=check data-price='".$row['price']."' class='service' name='pet[]' value ='".$row['services']."'";
    echo " />";
    echo $row['services'];

   }
```

Comment: Display them where and how? In what language? [edit] surely the value would just be `$row['services']` ?

Answer (score 0):

you should use "*checked*" property in case you have data. for more please see this
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car
```